# Referencing specific element(s) in a RelaxNG schema with externalRef

Tags: validation, xsd, relaxng

So I have one RelaxNG schema that references another:

```
<define name="review">
  <element name="review">
    <externalRef href="other.rng"/>
  </element>
</define>
```

other.rng:

```
<start>
  <choice>
    <ref name="good"/>
    <ref name="bad"/>
  </choice>
</start>

<define name="good"> 
  <element name="good"/>
</define>

<define name="bad">
  <element name="bad"/>
</define>
```

Is there any way I can import only `<good>`, but not allow `<bad>`?  The goal being:

```
<review><good/></review>: valid
<review><bad/></review>: invalid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar you import with `externalRef` can't be modified. To achieve the kind of validation you're after, I see this method :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<grammar xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"
    datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes">
    <include href="other.rng">
        <start combine="choice">
            <ref name="review"/>
        </start>
    </include>
    <define name="review">
        <element name="review">
            <ref name="good"/>
        </element>
    </define>
</grammar>
```

- You include the other schema.
- You override the `start` element in the include (`good` and `bad` elements won't be possible root).
  The [specification](http://relaxng.org/spec-20011203.html#IDAG3YR) says :

> If the include element has a start component, then all start
>   components are removed from the grammar element.

- You make a reference to the `good` element in your `review` definition.